# Issue with yarn's lockfile being modified

Tags: yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-lock.json

I'm using yarn berry, specifically version 3.0.0, but was also having the same issue with 2.4.2. When I run `yarn install --immutable` in CI I get the error:

`[2021-07-27T04:51:41Z] ➤ YN0028: │ The lockfile would have been modified by this install, which is explicitly forbidden`.

However when I run `yarn install` locally there are no changes to the `yarn.lock` file. I'm running the same node version `12.22.3` on my local machine and in the CI machine. The only other difference is that in CI, I'm running it inside an `Alpine` image whereas my local machine is a Mac, but I'm not reading that that should cause issues.

What can I do to debug this further?

Comment: did you found a solution to that problem?